# How to push an object into a one dimensional array and how to get individual item in array using ember.js

Tags: ember.js

Here is my code, I want to get userData details it is in the form of array,so i push that object into results array, am getting userData items into my result array but i can't access the individual item ,and that i want to display in my template using {{#each}}{{/each}}, help me to find this.

```
enter code here

addSuccess: function(userData) {
       Ember.Logger.log('user address data',userData); 
       var results = [];
       results.push(userData);
       this.set('result',results);
         Ember.Logger.log('result data          result',this.get('result.addresses.city'));
      this.send('btnClose');
      }
```

Comment: What is example value of userData? How do you want to loop on it in template? Can you give code of template?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, `userdata` is a plain object. Since Ember 2.1 you could iterate over an object with the [each-in](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Templates.helpers.html#method_each-in) helper. So your code would look something like:

**Controller/Route**

```
addSuccess: function(userData) {
    this.set('controller.userData', userData);    
}
```

**Template**

```
<ul>
    {{#each-in userData as |key value|}}
        <li>{{key}}: {{value}}</li>
    {{/each-in}}
</ul>
```